# Importing an ancestor module

Tags: python

I have a directory structure like this:

in src folder i have a module named util.py
in src/dir1/dir2 i have another module named client.py

i need to import util.py in client.py.

I have seen different questions about this topic in stackoverflow i tried different cases:

(relative path) in init.py of client.py folder i tried to do

```
from ... import util
```

but it gives me Import Error.

(absolute path) in the same init.py i tried:

```
import src.util
```

but it gives me the same error (Import Error).

I need a way that causes no problem with py2exe because i need it later.

Thanks for any answer.

I forgot to mention i'm using python2.7.1

Comment: the first two thing to look for are, is `src` folder in PYTHONPATH and do you have the `__init__.py` files?

Comment: Yes, src is in PYTHONPATH and i have init.py files.

Comment: just to be sure, you have `__init__.py` files, with double undersocres, right? Run `python` from src and try to import util, it should work.

Answer (score 1):

I usually do the following

```
import sys
sys.path.append('../..') #assure that src directory is in sys.path
import util
```

Comment: it seems the correct way to do but i don't get it working. I'm doing something in the wrong way. Do you put these lines of code in init.py ? What do you use in client.py for import util  ?

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to add `__init__.py` from the src folder and every subfolder containing files you want to import. You'll also need to be sure that the src is in your PYTHONPATH.

Assuming client.py is in your src folder and util.py is in src/dir1/dir2 (every directory in this path has a `__init__.py`, remember), you would import util from client like so:

```
import dir1.dir2.util
```

The `__init__.py` files can be empty.

Your src directory structure would end up looking like this (based on the example):

```
src/
|-- client.py
|-- dir1
|   |-- dir2
|   |   |-- __init__.py
|   |   `-- unit.py
|   `-- __init__.py
`-- __init__.py
```

Comment: The scenario is reversal. client.py is in src/dir1/dir2 and util.py in src. I want to import util.py in client.py.

Answer (score -1):

Well. First, put all the files in the same folder.
From there, you can say from .....util.py import util
or from ....util.py import *

If you just say import util.py, you will have to say util.(insert function here) whenever you are calling anything.

Also, you need an absolute directory if its not in the same folder. From C:/documents and settings/desktop (etc) util.py import util

Amendment:

For the the second section. I would suggest you do:
        from src/dir1/util.py import util

Comment: i don't want to put all the files in the same folder.

Comment: The next two paragraphs deal with it being in separate folders.